# Can't unify IEEEReal.rounding_mode with real

Tags: floating-point, integer, type-conversion, sml

Why do I get an error when I try to convert a real to an int like this?

```
fun stuff a  =
  Real.toInt a
```

Error:

```
Error-Can't unify IEEEReal.rounding_mode with real (Different type constructors) Found near stuff
(0.0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you overlooked that `Real.toInt : IEEEReal.rounding_mode -> real -> int`, i.e. takes an additional argument that specifies [how rounding is made](http://sml-family.org/Basis/ieee-float.html). In case you don't want to specify this extra argument, e.g. like

```
fun round x = Real.toInt IEEEReal.TO_NEAREST x
```

you could use one of the functions

- `Real.floor : real -> int` which assumes `IEEEReal.TO_NEGINF`,
- `Real.ceil : real -> int` which assumes `IEEEReal.TO_POSINF`,
- `Real.trunc : real -> int` which assumes `IEEEReal.TO_ZERO`, or
- `Real.round : real -> int` which assumes `IEEEReal.TO_NEAREST`.

Fun fact: The function `Real.toInt` is [actually defined in terms of these four functions](https://github.com/xyproto/smlnj/blob/master/sml/system/Basis/Implementation/real64.sml#L116).

Comment: Sometimes SML is needlessly pedantic. I think that this is one of those cases, but it is what it is.

Comment: especially if the real you want to convert is already in ending in .0 ... But I guess the computer does not know that?

Comment: @lotolmencre SML places a premium on having a very clear semantics. It is one of the few languages that actually *has* a formal semantics (as opposed to a formal syntax combined with a less formal semantics). This allows for code to be written so as to be provably correct. As part of the price for this, it forces programmers to be more explicit about things which in other languages would be left implicit.

Comment: @lotolmencre: It is hard to know at compile-time if a *real* ends in .0. Languages that dynamically convert between the types *float* and *int* don't either, and they typically even assume what way you want to round. If *you* know that this number always ends in .0, then there is no reason to use a *real* to represent it, is there? Deciding if a *real* ends in .0 isn't entirely trivial [due to imprecision](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/). Assuming it always ends in .0, but converting it from *real* to *int*, sounds like a job for `Real.trunc`.